setTimeout() is not Working in Jets Unit Test
Here I have perform testing on jest. When I tested for setTimeout() function, it didn’t work. Any help would be appreciated.
I have followed this documentation:
https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks
Additional Details
Framework: Vue.js
Testing Library: Jest
Problem: The changeRoute method is not being called even after advancing the timers by the specified time.
What I've Tried
Ensured jest.useFakeTimers() is called before any timers are set.
Verified the setTimeout spy is properly set up.
Double-checked that submitCall is awaited before advancing timers.
     async submitCall(error, data, message) {
  if (isBlank(error)) {
    this.successMessage = message;
    
    if (isBlank(data)) {
      await this.loadData(this.currentReportId);
      
      if (hasValue(this.successMessage)) {
        await new Promise((resolve) => {
          setTimeout(async () => {
            this.changeRoute({ name: 'report' });
            resolve();
          }, 5000);
        });
      }
    } else {
      await this.pageRedirection(data);
    }
  }
}

        
        
        
           
        //Test case
        
           
it('should call changeRoute after 5 seconds', async () => {
  jest.useFakeTimers();
  jest.spyOn(window, 'setTimeout');
  
  wrapper.vm.changeRoute = jest.fn();
  wrapper.vm.pageRedirection = jest.fn();

  expect(wrapper.vm.changeRoute).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

  const submitCallPromise = wrapper.vm.submitCall('', '', 'success message');

  jest.advanceTimersByTime(5000);

  await submitCallPromise;

  expect(wrapper.vm.changeRoute).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});

Error:
ModuleAggregateError

I think you should create a promise from the setTimeout and call it with async, otherwise your async submit function will return before the timeout has passed.

I have tried with promise too but that also didn’t worked

@JayPatel What did you try? Code is not formatted and not easy to read. setTimeout ( handler: async ) → { - what does this mean?

@EstusFlask
I have updated my  code  with promise

The problem is that advanceTimersByTime should happen after setTimeout, this isn't so now. The primary obstacle I see is loadData. It's unknown what it is, but it needs to be mocked. If you mocked it to resolve instantly, it should be something like const submitCallPromise = ...; await flushPromises(); expect(setTimeout).toBeCalledTimes(1);  jest.advanceTimersByTime(5000);  await submitCallPromise; expect(...). You can add an assertion for setTimeout  spy to make the test more rigid and easier  to debug when it fails
